# sed backreference not being found

Tags: sed, backreference

I am trying to use 'sed' to replace a list of paths in a file with another path.

An example string to process is:

```
/path/to/file/block
```

I want to replace **/path/to/file** with something else.

I have Tried

```
sed -r '/\s(\S+)\/block/s/\1/new_path/'
```

I know it's finding the matching string but I'm getting an invalid back reference error.

How can I do this?

Comment: `sed -E 's@\s(\S+)/block@\1/new_path@' <<< " /path/to/file/block"`? You may also use `sed -r '/\s(\S+)\/block/s//\1\/new_path/' <<< "$s"` but I'd recommend a straight-forward substitution here.

Answer (score 1):

This may do:

```
echo "/path/to/file/block" | sed -r 's|/\S*/(block)|/newpath/\1|'
/newpath/block
```

Test

```
echo "test=/path/file test2=/path/to/file/block test3=/home/root/file" | sed -r 's|/\S*/(block)|/newpath/\1|'
test=/path/file test2=/newpath/block test3=/home/root/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Back-references always refer to the *pattern* of the `s` command, not to any *address* (before the command).

However, in this case, there's no need for addressing: we can apply the substitution to all lines (and it will change only lines where it matches), so we can write:

```
s,\s(\S+)/block/, \1/new_path,
```

(I added a space to the RHS, as I'm guessing you didn't mean to overwrite that; also used a different separator to reduce the need for backslashes.)